# The SSL Store and WHMCS Renewal Modul Error

Tags: ssl, whmcs

if someone knows what causing this error and how to fix it, there support is way to slow. So client paid for renewal but once i try to execute renewal command (Thesslstorefullv2 / Renew) via module i got following error.

**Module Command Error
The order is not in the state for renewal.
**

Its certificate is Comodo SSL Certificate (DV) and its 24 months period.

Thank you very much <3

Well it work well until know so i have no idea what to try, only thing i tried is to restart the API keys but that dose seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate is most likely not due for a renew but rather a *reissue*.
The SSL certificate will last for 396 days. After this, the certificate will need to be reissued, even though you paid for 2, 3 or 4 years up front. It needs to be reissued at least once per year.